# Sql Oracle 12c Trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle12c

I need some help.
I'm trying to create a Trigger that execute a procedure whenever insert, delete or update operations are done on a specific table.
This is the trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER NQDI.GAV_TRG 
AFTER INSERT or UPDATE or DELETE ON D_GAV
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    PRC_FILL_D_GAV(:old.report_name);
END;
```

Unofortunately, since the trigger starts before any commit has been done and I need to read from the same table, it gives me the 'D_GAV table is being modified can't be read' error.
Besides, the **FOR EACH ROW** makes the trigger start for every record changed, while I want the trigger to start only at the end, when every update, insert or delete has been committed, but I haven't find a way to preserve the **:old.report_name** while doing this.
I know I could do what I want with an "up and running process", but I'd like to avoid that. Is there any other solution that I'm overlooking?

Comment: Just remove the `FOR EACH ROW` clause, then it fires once per statement instead of once per record. However, in this case you have no access to `:old.report_name`

Comment: yes I thought about that, but it gives me the error '"NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers"' while I absolutely need that variable

Comment: You cannot separate a trigger from transaction, i.e. COMMIT. Put all in a procedure and perform there all the operation you need.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do in `PRC_FILL_D_GAV(:old.report_name)`?.

Comment: @ Wernfried Domscheit 
I understand, but can't do that. There are other processes that can change that table (not under my control), hence I need the trigger to execute the procedure. Otherwise I have to check constantly if it has been changed.
@ Kaushik Nayak the procedure would modify some records on toher tables related to the D_GAV, but there are some fields who are read from the D_GAV itself.

Comment: `:old.report_name` will always be null case of insert. Is this intended?

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner Not really, I've just semplified the code, but in the actual one it's not null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a **compound trigger**. After each row event you insert the data into an array. And after the statement you loop through the data and call your procedure.

```
create or replace trigger nqdi.gav_trg
for insert or update or delete on d_gav compound trigger

  type type_table_of_gav is table of d_gav%rowtype;
  v_gavs type_table_of_gav := type_table_of_gav();

  after each row is
  begin
    v_gavs.extend(1);
    v_gavs(v_gavs.count).report_name := coalesce(:old.report_name, :new.report_name);
  end after each row;

  after statement is
  begin
    for i in 1 .. v_gavs.count loop
      prc_fill_d_gav(v_gavs(i).report_name);
    end loop;
  end after statement;

end gav_trg;
```